# How to determine the optimized correlation between 2 sets of data?

Tags: excel

There are 2 sets of data under column A & B, and there is a input value in 
cell C1.
Assumethe data set under column A is fixed, and we try to shift forward 
and backward on the data set under column B. 
If the input value is 0 in cell C1, then there is no shift movement for the 
data set on B column.
If the input value is 5 in cell C1, then the data set on B column is shift 
up 5 cells.
If the input value is -5 in cell C1, then the data set on B column is shift 
down 5 cells.
As the data set on B column shift upward or downward, the correlation 
between 2 sets of data changes. 
My objective is to determine the optimized value in cell C1, therefore, it 
will return the maximum correlation between 2 sets of data. 
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to determine the optimized 
correlation between the 2 sets of data this way using Excel?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to have the following formula in D1:

```
=CORREL($A$1:$A$7,OFFSET($B$1,C1,0,7))
```

Assuming you calculate the correlation on 7 points in my example. To be able to use negative shift, you need to start at Bxx, say B5 to be able to shift up to 4 cells up for example.

You can then put values in C1, C2 etc. for various scenarios (from -5 in C1 to +5 in C11 for example) and drag the formula in D1 accordingly. Then looking for the max is easy, either looking at it or using the `MAX` function.

Comment: Thanks. But, Solver is not working the way you have suggested. I want to specifically know how to use solver. I think its not working with offset function.

Comment: @SujayPrasadSrivastava Just tried the solver and indeed it does not seem to be able to work with the offset...

Comment: @andyholaday yes that was the idea of the last paragraph.

Comment: Yeah the column approach is a fine way of finding the max correlation. Let me know if anyone has a better method.